# Understanding the Proof for Properties of Mollifiers on Evan's PDE

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

This is from the appendix of Evan's PDE on mollifiers. Let $f \in L^p$, I would like to show that the mollification $f^\epsilon \to f$ almost everywhere as $\epsilon \to 0$. I shall attach the definition of mollification here:
[image: 1]

The proof given by Evans is attached below. I am having trouble to understand the **last** inequality in the following picture: [image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use that $|B(x,\epsilon)| = |B(0,1)|\epsilon^n$ and that $\eta(\frac{x-y}{\epsilon}) \leq C$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just so I understand it completely, you are saying the following: Since $\eta$ is compactly supported smooth function, it is bounded by some constant, say $M \in \mathbf{N}$. Moreover, we have $\frac{1}{\epsilon^n} = \frac{|B(0, 1)|}{|B(x, \epsilon)|}$. Therefore, we have $\frac{1}{\epsilon^n} \int_{B(x, \epsilon)} \eta(\frac{x - y}{\epsilon})|f(y) - f(x)| \, dy \leq \frac{M}{\epsilon^n} \int_{B(x, \epsilon)} |f(y) - f(x)| \, dy = \frac{M|B(0, 1)|}{|B(x, \epsilon)|} \int_{B(x, \epsilon)} |f(y) - f(x)|$. Set $C := M|B(0, 1)|$, we are done. Is this correct?

Comment: @Mathematics_Beginner Yes, that should be correct.